# fontFamilyFallback not working for Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts, flutter-web

`fontFamilyFallback` isn't working in Flutter web. I've tried many things but nothing worked. It's very easy to reproduce.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Run the code sample 1, in debug mode in Chrome.
2. Run the code sample 2, in debug mode in Chrome.

The only difference between code sample 1 and code sample 2 is the `fontFamily`. In code sample 1 it is set as `"Helvetica"`. In code sample 2 it is set as `"Some font that doestn exist"`.

#### Expected results:

**Expected result for code sample 1:**

Text should be rendered with `fontFamily` (Helvetica).

[image: Expected result for code sample 1]

**Expected result for code sample 2:**

Text should be rendered with `fontFamilyFallback` (Palatino), as the `fontFamily` is not available.

[image: Expected result for code sample 2]

---

#### Actual results:

**In code sample 1, the resulted is correct**, as expected. The font rendered is Helvetica, the `fontFamily` specified.

However, **in code sample 2, the result is wrong**. The font rendered is the system default (SF Pro), but it should be the first font in `fontFamilyFallback` (which is Palatino). Instead, Flutter just ignores `fontFamilyFallback`.

###### Note that the problem is not Palatino. If I set `fontFamily` as Palatino, it does work (this is how I made the image for "expected result for code sample 2").

[image: Result 2]

### Code samples

Code sample 1:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: const [
        Text(
          "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n- + 0123456789",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
            fontFamilyFallback: [
              "Palatino",
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Code sample 2:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: const [
        Text(
          "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n- + 0123456789",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Some font that doestn exist',
            fontFamilyFallback: [
              "Palatino",
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

### Logs

`flutter analyze`

```
No issues found! (ran in 1.4s)
```

`flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.4, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm, locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 3.0.4 at /Users/rafaelguimaraes/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 85684f9300 (6 weeks ago), 2022-06-30 13:22:47 -0700
    • Engine revision 6ba2af10bb
    • Dart version 2.17.5
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.


[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] VS Code (version 1.70.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.46.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 104.0.5112.79

[!] HTTP Host Availability
    ✗ HTTP host "https://cocoapods.org/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Failed host lookup: 'cocoapods.org'
    ✗ HTTP host "https://maven.google.com/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Failed host lookup: 'maven.google.com'
    ✗ HTTP host "https://pub.dev/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Failed host lookup: 'pub.dev'
    ✗ HTTP host "https://cloud.google.com/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Failed host lookup: 'cloud.google.com'

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add fonts to pubspec.yaml like this,

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

This will work. You should add fonts to pubspec.yaml

For more:
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts

Comment: Yeah, I'm were of this.The problem is that the fonts I am specifying are available in the computer, so I don't have to add them to pubspec.yaml. Like Palatino, it works if I put it as the primary font, but if I put it as the fallback font, it's not called, like I demonstrated.

Comment: And it works just fine in macOS, just not in Web.